# Blogger html div positioning

Tags: html, position, blogger

I took an html template from internet and altered it (I have permission to, I will add credits when I finally get this thing to work.) but I want the blogposts to show a bit higher than before. I tried a lot of things already, I thought I was supposed to change the position or margin of either the content wrapper or the main wrapper but none of it worked.

This is the coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
    <b:skin><![CDATA[/*
-----------------------------------------------
Name:    VanillaLooks
Author:   Kelly Vuijst
----------------------------------------------- */
#navbar-iframe {
display: none !important;
}
/* Variable definitions
   ====================

   <Variable name="textcolor" description="Text Color"
             type="color" default="#333" value="#333333">
   <Variable name="linkcolor" description="Link Color"
             type="color" default="#EF3665" value="#EF3665">
   <Variable name="pagetitlecolor" description="Blog Title Color"
             type="color" default="#fff" value="#ffffff">
   <Variable name="descriptioncolor" description="Blog Description Color"
             type="color" default="#eee" value="#eeeeee">
   <Variable name="titlecolor" description="Post Title Color"
             type="color" default="#B81840" value="#B81840">
   <Variable name="sidebarcolor" description="Sidebar Title Color"
             type="color" default="#EF3665" value="#EF3665">
   <Variable name="sidebartextcolor" description="Sidebar Text Color"
             type="color" default="#666" value="#666666">
   <Variable name="visitedlinkcolor" description="Visited Link Color"
             type="color" default="#EF3665" value="#EF3665">
   <Variable name="bodyfont" description="Text Font"
             type="font" default="normal normal 110% Arial, Serif" value="normal normal 110% Arial, Serif">
   <Variable name="headerfont" description="Sidebar Title Font"
             type="font"
             default="bold 140%/1.4em 'Arial',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif" value="bold 140%/1.4em 'Arial',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif">
   <Variable name="pagetitlefont" description="Blog Title Font"
             type="font"
             default="bold 260% Lobster,Serif" value="bold 260% Lobster,Serif">
   <Variable name="descriptionfont" description="Blog Description Font"
             type="font"
             default="italic 100% 'Georgia',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif" value="italic 100% 'Georgia',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif">
   <Variable name="postfooterfont" description="Post Footer Font"
             type="font"
             default="italic 90%/1.4em 'Georgia',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif" value="italic 90%/1.4em 'Georgia',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif">
   <Variable name="startSide" description="Side where text starts in blog language"
             type="automatic" default="left" value="left">
   <Variable name="endSide" description="Side where text ends in blog language"
             type="automatic" default="right" value="right">
*/

/* Use this with templates/template-treecol.html */

body {
background:url("http://i41.tinypic.com/faoahy.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #F6E5E0;
color:$textcolor;
font:small Georgia Serif;
margin:0;
text-align:center;
}
a:link {
color:$linkcolor;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited {
color:$visitedlinkcolor;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
color:#333333;
text-decoration:underline;
}
a img {
border-width:0;
}
#header-wrapper {
height:200px;
margin:0 auto;
width:976px;
}
#content-wrapper {
position-top:100px;
}
#header-inner {
background-position:center center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#header {
color:$pagetitlecolor;
text-align:left;
}
#header h1 {
font: $pagetitlefont;
letter-spacing:1px;
margin:0;
padding:70px 50px 2px;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000000;
text-transform:none;
}
#header a {
color:$pagetitlecolor;
text-decoration:none;
}
#header a:hover {
color:#F6E5E0;
}
#header .description {
font: $descriptionfont;
color: $descriptioncolor;
letter-spacing:0.2em;
margin:0;
max-width:700px;
padding:0 50px 15px;
text-transform:none;
}
#header img {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#outer-wrapper {
font: $bodyfont;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
width:976px;
}
#placeholder {
display:block;
float:right;
height:45px;
margin-right:191px;
margin-top:96px;
width:173px;
}
#main-wrapper {
float:left;
position-top:100px;
margin-bottom:-40px;
margin-left:25px;
margin-top:0px;
overflow:hidden;
width:570px;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
float:right;
margin-right:30px;
margin-top:48px;
overflow:hidden;
width:320px;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
h2 {
font:$headerfont;
color:$sidebarcolor;
letter-spacing:0;
margin:0;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-left:61px;
padding-top:20px;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
text-transform:none;
}
h2.date-header {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
color:#777777;
font:italic 12px georgia;
height:10px;
letter-spacing:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
text-transform:none;
}
.post {
margin:0.5em 0 1.5em;
padding-bottom:1.5em;
}
.post h3 {
background:url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_uW7vQWFtStk/TDw71JjPkUI/AAAAAAAAAok/tzJPjG4heWw/s1600/under-title.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
color:$titlecolor;
font:italic 170% georgia;
height:55px;
margin:0.25em 0 10px;
padding:0 0 5px;
text-align:center;
}
.post h3 a, .post h3 a:visited, .post h3 strong {
color:$titlecolor;
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
.post h3 strong, .post h3 a:hover {
color:#333333;
}
body#layout #footer {
display:none;
}
body#layout #crosscol-wrapper {
display:none;
}
body#layout #addthis_toolbox {
display:none;
}
body#layout #searchbox {
display:none;
}
.post-body {
line-height:1.6em;
margin:0 0 0.75em;
}
.post-body blockquote {
line-height:1.3em;
}
.post-footer {
border-top:1px dotted #F88C8C;
color:#777777;
font:$postfooterfont;
letter-spacing:0;
margin:0.75em 0;
padding:5px 10px;
text-transform:none;
}
.comment-link {
margin-left:0.6em;
}
.post img, table.tr-caption-container {
border:3px solid #F6E5E0;
padding:1px;
}
.tr-caption-container img {
border:medium none;
padding:0;
}
.post blockquote {
margin:1em 20px;
}
.post blockquote p {
margin:0.75em 0;
}
#comments h4 {
color:#666666;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:0;
line-height:1.4em;
margin:1em 0;
text-transform:none;
}
#comments-block {
line-height:1.6em;
margin:1em 0 1.5em;
}
#comments-block .comment-author {
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F6E5E0;
border:1px solid #F6E5E0;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:normal;
margin-right:20px;
padding:5px;
}
#comments .blogger-comment-icon, .blogger-comment-icon {
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F6E5E0;
border-color:#F6E5E0;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px 1px 1px;
line-height:16px;
padding:5px;
}
#comments-block .comment-body {
border-left:1px solid #F6E5E0;
border-right:1px solid #F6E5E0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:20px;
padding:7px;
}
#comments-block .comment-footer {
border-bottom:1px solid #F6E5E0;
border-left:1px solid #F6E5E0;
border-right:1px solid #F6E5E0;
font-size:11px;
line-height:1.4em;
margin:-0.25em 20px 2em 0;
padding:5px;
text-transform:none;
}
#comments-block .comment-body p {
margin:0 0 0.75em;
}
.deleted-comment {
color:gray;
font-style:italic;
}
#blog-pager-newer-link {
float:left;
}
#blog-pager-older-link {
float:right;
}
#blog-pager {
text-align:center;
}
.feed-links {
clear:both;
line-height:2.5em;
}
.sidebar {
color:$sidebartextcolor;
line-height:1.5em;
}
.sidebar ul {
list-style:none outside none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.sidebar li {
border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;
line-height:1.5em;
margin:0;
padding:2px;
}
.sidebar .widget, .main .widget {
margin:0 0 1.5em;
}
.main .Blog {
border-bottom-width:0;
}
.profile-img {
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
float:left;
margin:0 5px 5px 0;
padding:4px;
}
.profile-data {
color:#999999;
font:bold 78%/1.6em 'Trebuchet MS',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif;
letter-spacing:0.1em;
margin:0;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.profile-datablock {
margin:0.5em 0;
}
.profile-textblock {
line-height:1.6em;
margin:0.5em 0;
}
.profile-link {
font:78% 'Trebuchet MS',Trebuchet,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif;
letter-spacing:0.1em;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#footer-bg {
background:url("http://i41.tinypic.com/2603ibo.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
height:170px;
}
#footer {
background:url("http://i44.tinypic.com/15x8kr9.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
clear:both;
color:#F6E5E0;
font:11px arial;
height:50px;
letter-spacing:0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:120px;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000000;
text-transform:none;
width:971px;
}
#footer a {
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.fright {
float:right;
margin-top:3px;
text-align:right;
width:44%;
}
.fleft {
float:left;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:2px;
text-align:left;
width:42%;
}
.feed-links {
display:none;
}
#wrapper {
background:url("http://i43.tinypic.com/ilejnq.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
#content-bg {
background:url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_uW7vQWFtStk/TDtxozDPxQI/AAAAAAAAAn0/LWJL5xZX7B0/s1600/content-bg.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
margin:0 auto;
width:976px;
}
#PageList1 {
font:italic 110% georgia;
height:50px;
margin-left:50px;
padding-top:18px;
width:700px;
}
#searchbox {
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
background:url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_uW7vQWFtStk/TDxCifGlCkI/AAAAAAAAAo0/RyDNKX7ATvM/s1600/search-box.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border-left:1px solid #EEEEEE;
display:block;
float:right;
height:45px;
margin-right:191px;
margin-top:96px;
width:173px;
}
#searchbox .textfield {
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border:0 none;
float:left;
height:15px;
margin:14px 1px 10px 20px;
width:107px;
}
#searchbox .button {
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border:0 none;
cursor:pointer;
float:left;
height:30px;
margin-left:2px;
margin-top:6px;
width:30px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper .widget-content {
padding:0 25px;
}
.PageList li a {
color:#C1987C;
font-weight:bold;
}
.PageList li a:hover {
color:#EDD3C0;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
.PageList li.selected a {
color:#EDD3C0;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}

#addthis_toolbox {
float:right;
margin-left:179px;
margin-top:66px;
}
.addthis_button_rss {
margin-right:5px;
}
.addthis_button_twitter {
margin-right:5px;
}
.col-left {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:48%;
}
.col-right {
float:right;
width:48%;
}
.post-author {
background:url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_8GxSJXcDIwk/TBNBFo0rK-I/AAAAAAAABq8/VO_ATeuF6sM/s1600/aaa.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
padding-left:20px;
}
.post-comment-link a {
background:url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_8GxSJXcDIwk/TBM6sX5_MNI/AAAAAAAABp8/2RwKjFNZjcQ/s1600/1276328597_comment.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
padding-left:20px;
}
.post-labels {
background:url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_8GxSJXcDIwk/TBNALDZe_0I/AAAAAAAABqk/cS_OBWXZEQs/s1600/1276330011_tags.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
padding-left:20px;
}
]]></b:skin>
  </head>

  <body>
<div id='content-bg'>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='outer-wrapper'><div id='wrap2'>

    <!-- skip links for text browsers -->
    <span id='skiplinks' style='display:none;'>
      <a href='#main'>skip to main </a> |
      <a href='#sidebar'>skip to sidebar</a>
    </span>
 <div id='crosscol-wrapper' style='text-align:center'>
        <b:section class='crosscol' id='crosscol'>
<b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' title='Pages' type='PageList'/>
</b:section>
      </div>
    <div id='header-wrapper'>
      <b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
<b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='VanillaLooks.blogspot.com (Kop)' type='Header'/>
</b:section>
    </div>

    <div id='content-wrapper'>
<div id='placeholder'>
</div>
<div id='addthis_toolbox'> 

</div> 
      <div id='main-wrapper'>
        <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='no'>
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blogberichten' type='Blog'/>
</b:section>
      </div>

      <div id='sidebar-wrapper'>
        <b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebar' preferred='yes'>
<b:widget id='Slideshow1' locked='false' title='Slideshow' type='Slideshow'/>
<b:widget id='Followers1' locked='false' title='Followers' type='Followers'/>
</b:section>
<div id='2columns'>
<div class='col-left'>
<b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebar2' preferred='yes'>
<b:widget id='BlogArchive1' locked='false' title='Archief' type='BlogArchive'/>
</b:section>
</div>
<div class='col-right'>
<b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebar3' preferred='yes'/>
</div></div>
      </div>

      <!-- spacer for skins that want sidebar and main to be the same height-->
      <div class='clear'>&#160;</div>

    </div> <!-- end content-wrapper -->


  </div></div> <!-- end outer-wrapper --> </div></div>
<div id='footer-bg'> 
<div id='footer'> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see right off is that main-wrapper has a negative bottom margin, which would pull it downwards, not upwards. Can you provide a link to the live page? That would be a lot easier to debug. :) In general, to move something up you could use a smaller or negative margin-top value, but it also depends on what style of positioning you're using (float, static, relative, absolute) and how the elements are interacting with one another.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
This is the link; http://vanillalooks.blogspot.com/
It totally worked with the negative margin-top, thanks!

Comment: Kelly, that blog is "open to invited readers only." Would you mind making it public so we can help find your issue?

Comment: Chad, I didn't even knew that. Thanks for telling me. The problem is solved now though, thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it taken care of! BTW, most browsers have a tool to let you examine the CSS and debug problems more easily; FireBug for Firefox, right-click and click "Inspect Element" in Google Chrome and so on. Those are very, very handy tools so it's worthwhile to play with them and read up on how to use them.